# Fetching list of entries with their field name into dictionary DJango Models

Tags: python, json, django, django-models, django-views

I have the list of ids

```
   id_list = [1,2,3,4]
```

I am using for loop to fetch the result

```
   roles = []
   for id in id_list:
       roles.append(Role.objects.filter(id = id).values('id' , 'name'))
```

This give me the result but in this form:

```
   roles = [[{id:1, name:employee}], [{id:2, name=staff}], [{id:3,name=driver}] , [{id:4, name=staffboy}]]
```

But I want data in a dictionary so that also relatable for JSON response

```
   roles = [{id:1,name:employee} , {id:2,name:staff} , {id:3,name:driver} , {id:4,name:staffboy}]
```

Any other method of fetching the list of results in a format I want?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this even without the `for` loop, you can try something like below -

```
roles = Role.objects.filter(id__in=[1,2,3,4]).values('id' , 'name')
```

Make sure its a double underscore.

But this will not be a python `list`. `roles` would be a `QuerySet`. You can convert to python `list` like below -

```
list(roles)
```

Comment: @VishalSingh: yes without square brackets, as `id_list` is already a list. something like this - `id__in=id_list`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `extend` instead of `append`.

```
roles = []
for id in id_list:
    roles.extend(Role.objects.filter(id=id).values("id", "name"))
```